# Error when I try recover the current value of a column in my database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a column in my table called `AllowComent`. This column has bit data type.

In my C# code I try recover the value

```
protected string RecoverAllowComent(string id)
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(_conexao))
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
            comando.CommandText = "SELECT AllowComent FROM San_Blog WHERE Id = @Id";
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", id));
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.Connection = conexao;
            conexao.Open();
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }
            else                    
                return "False";
         }
     }
     catch
     {
         return "False";
     }
}
```

But I got the error 
`Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ''1'' to data type int.`

Comment: @JustinNiessner id is Int

Comment: Why not change comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", id));
to 
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id); //assuming id is of IntType make sure that id is declared as an Integer can you show how id is declared and where you declare it

Comment: What type is id column of the table and data type of id variable in C#? Also, if the result is going to be of 1 row with 1 column, use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).

Comment: also change your method signature from protected string RecoverAllowComent(string id)
to protected bool RecoverAllowComent(string id) then change your return type to true catch return false;

Comment: Color me a bit crazy here, but if `id` is an `int` in the database, why exactly does this method have it as a `string` parameter? It does nothing "stringly" with it, so why not pass it in as an `int`? Let calling code convert it if necessary.

Comment: Also, `SqlCommand` implements `IDisposable`, so wrap its creation and usage in a `using` block much like your `SqlConnection` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing passing `id` which has type string. You need to pass `int` to `parameter` id.

Change

```
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", id));
```

To

```
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", int.Parse(id)));
```

*If it is possible you can change type of your parameter ID of RecoverAllowComent to int to get away from type casting string to int.*

Comment: @Adil I update my question, and now we can see that my method receives ID as string yet

Comment: I have updated my answer what is type of id in your database table?

Comment: In my database ID is int data type.

Comment: If it is possible you can change type of your parameter ID of RecoverAllowComent to int to get away from type casting string to int.

Comment: Try the `ExecuteScalar` if it is a case of 1 row, 1 column being returned.